# How do I initialize a 2D char array with dynamic memory allocation in C?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, character

I'm writing a function that copies the contents of a text file (arranged into a table) into a 2D array, just without the spaces. For example, if table.txt is

```
A  B  C  
D  E  F  
G  H  I
```

then the generated array would be equivalent to

```
char tableArray[ROWS][COLS] = {{'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E', 'F'}, {'G', 'H', 'I'}};
```

I'm having trouble with the initialization of said array.

The function currently looks like this:

```
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 3
char tableArray[ROWS][COLS];
//proper initialization of tableArray here. Not sure what to put
void copyTable(){
    //copies the characters of the table into an array
    FILE *fp = fopen("table.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("No file found.");
        return;
    }
    char c;
    int currentRow;
    int currentCol;
    //Iterate through the file character by character
    for (currentRow = 0; currentRow < ROWS; currentRow++) {
        for (currentCol = 0; currentCol < COLS; currentCol++) {
            c = fgetc(fp);
            if (!(c == ' ')) {
                tableArray[currentRow][currentCol] = c;
            }
            fgetc(fp); //skip newline character at end of row
        }

    }
    tableArray[ROWS][COLS] = '\0';

}
```

But this code won't work due to a lack of memory allocation. I tried doing something like

```
char tableArray[ROWS][COLS];

int** tableArray;
tableArray = (int**)malloc(ROWS * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    tableArray[i] = (int*)malloc(COLS * sizeof(int));
}
```

but I don't really understand what that code does, and it yields an error: 'tableArray' does not name a type, which I've failed to fix.

So how do I properly initialize tableArray? If there's another problem in the function irrespective of this part, please let me know.

Comment: I see `f (!(c == ' ')) {`, but what if `c == '\n'` or `c == EOF` or some other space?  I'd expect `fgetc(fp); //skip newline character at end of row` after the `for (currentCol = 0; currentCol < COLS; currentCol++) {` loop.

Comment: If c=='\n' it should be at the end of the line anyway, and the inner loop should have completed. Same for EOF.

Comment: `char tableArray[ROWS][COLS];` and `int** tableArray;` both define objects named `tableArray`.  Can't do that.  Use one.

Comment: Fouad Saffar, I agree about the _should_, yet robust code detects unexpected input - else it is _brittle_.  IAC, consider using `fgets()` to read a _line_ of file input into a _string_ and then parse the string.

Comment: For _dynamic memory_, you want a pointer.  For a _2D char array_ use `char tableArray[ROWS][COLS]`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica for 2D dynamic array you want pointer to array

Comment: @0___________ Ture, yet OP true goals are not clear and so I do my best to divine them and interpret OP's response.

Answer (score 1):

When we know the data dimensions (e.g. 3x3), call a function to handle the allocation and reading.

Allocate to the referenced object, not to the type.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Test for allocation success.

Read with `fgetc()` and test it.

Use `size_t` for sizing and indexing.

I'd recommend `unsigned char` for the data type as it is more clear on what is being saved the `char`, but use whatever type you want.

```
unsigned char** read_char_matrix(FILE *inf, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
  unsigned char **table = malloc(sizeof table[0] * rows);
  if (table == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    table[c] = malloc(sizeof table[c][0] * cols);
    if (table[c] == NULL) {
      while (c > 0) {
        free(table[--c]);
      }
      free(table);
      return NULL;
    }
  }

  for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      int ch = fgetc(inf);
      if (!isalpha(ch)) {
        TBD_Code_to_handle_error();
      }
      table[r][c] = (unsigned char) ch;
      ch = fgetc(inf);
      if (!isspace(ch)) {
        TBD_Code_to_handle_error();
      }
    }
  }
  return table;
}
```

Comment: What is "col c" in the first for loop?

Comment: @FouadSaffar Coding error corrected.

Comment: I think there are some other errors, like char **table being assigned to malloc, which is a void function? And same thing with table[c]? Am I missing something?

Comment: @FouadSaffar `void *malloc(size_t size);` returns a `void *`, not `void`.  A `void *` can be assigned to any object pointer type like `char **` - no cast needed.  If you are getting a error without the cast --> are you using a C compiler or C++ one?

Comment: I am using a C++ compiler

Comment: How would I change the code to be compatible with a C++ 14 compiler?

Comment: @FouadSaffar by writing it using `C++` language instead of `C`. In C++ we try to avoid explicit memory allocations and naked pointers. If you want to use C++ compiler, write in C++.

Comment: You tagged your question ‘C’. C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: @FouadSaffar Why tag question as C and then use a C++ compiler?

Comment: @FouadSaffar Simply stop using the C++ compiler for compiling C. C++ has not been a superset of C since the 1980s somewhere when it was an early draft called "C with classes". Anyone who told you that C++ is a superset of C is incompetent and shouldn't be teaching either language.